# fulfillment of : ETSI EN 319 411-2 or ETSI TS 101 456 - "7.2.2 Certification authority key backup using secure world daily backup on tape

Tags: backup

Can someone explain me how one CA can fulfill normative request:

[ETSI EN 319 411-2](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319400_319499/31941102/01.00.00_20/en_31941102v010000c.pdf) or ETSI TS 101 456

> "7.2.2 Certification authority key storage, backup and recovery ... c)
>   the CA private signing key shall be backed up, stored and recovered
>   only by personnel in trusted roles using, at least, dual control in a
>   physically secure environment (see clause 7.4.4). The number of
>   personnel authorized to carry out this function shall be kept to a
>   minimum and be consistent with the CA's practices;"

- and have automatic daily backup on tapes of whole "secure world" (including CA private key) in order to achieve fast disaster recovery solution.

I understand that the secure world is created under dual control but daily backups are done automatically.

Also I know that the recovery can be done with dual control only but is it according to ETSI requirement written above?

The most unclear point for me is related to daily backups which mean that CA would have 30 backups of CA private key on tape each month. 
Is that allowed?

How regular CA can achieve this ETSI request using Thales nChiper with secure world and backup on tapes?

Answer (score 0):

The security world can be created with dual control ACS cards 2/3 should work fine (`EN 319 411-1`).

I'm no auditor, but you can just back up the CAs keys once on multiple hard drives (after a key ceremony, then store the drives in a safe) and then just ignore the keys when doing daily backups and just save the security world configuration.

Keep in mind that he CAs keys are encrypted and cannot be used outside the HSM.